# How to do integration test with activemq and spring3?

Tags: spring, testing, activemq-classic, mockito

I have a code like this, but I'm not sure how would I test this piece of of code that I extracted from my project. I'm using Spring3 and ActiveMQ. And I'm using spring to do remote HTTPInvoker that's why I have the GateWay. So, when I call method `submit` in my `Gateway`, it's going to send a JMS message via JMSDispatcher. How would you inject `JmsTemplate` to `Gateway`? As far as I know, if I want to test JMS I have to configure it in application-context.xml in Spring and inject overridden JmsTemplate. So, I could test the message inside the queue? But I can't inject `JmsTemplate` to `Gateway` since Mockito will complain about not having that field inside `Gateway`.

```
public class Gateway {
    @Autowired
    private ProcessController processController;
    public void submit() {
         processControllerFactory.submit();
    }

}

public ProcessController {
    @Autowired
    private JMSDispatcher jmsDispatcher;
    public void submit() {
          // do something
          jmsDispatcher.send(message);
    }
}

public JMSDispatcher {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("someJmsTemplate")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void send(MessageCreator message) {
          jmsTemplate.send(message);
    }
}
```